# Thread dumps: The hexa-decimal (lock, conditions etc) - what are they, and how to understand what they are?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning to understand Thread dumps, and I created a sample application to simulate `deadlock` condition.

The below is full code:

**Thread1.java**

```
package com.example.threads.deadlock;

public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private Object _lock1;

    private Object _lock2;

    public Thread1(Object _lock1, Object _lock2) {
        this._lock1 = _lock1;
        this._lock2 = _lock2;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (_lock1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (_lock2) {
                for (;;)
                    ;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Thread2.java**

```
package com.example.threads.deadlock;

public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    private Object _lock1;

    private Object _lock2;

    public Thread2(Object _lock1, Object _lock2) {
        this._lock1 = _lock1;
        this._lock2 = _lock2;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (_lock2) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (_lock1) {
                for (;;)
                    ;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**MainApp.java**

```
package com.example.threads.deadlock.main;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

import com.example.threads.deadlock.Thread1;
import com.example.threads.deadlock.Thread2;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object _lock1 = new Object();
        Object _lock2 = new Object();

        System.out.println("_lock 1 is " + _lock1 + " _lock2 is " + _lock2);

        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(_lock1, _lock2);

        Thread t2 = new Thread2(_lock1, _lock2);

        t1.start();

        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(9999999999999999L);

    }
}
```

As expected, I see `deadlock` in Thread-dump. My aim is to de-mystify the various `hex-numbers` which I see in "lock" , "condition" etc.

The below is the output for `_lock1` and `_lock2` in sysout of `MainApp.java`

```
_lock 1 is java.lang.Object@7852e922 _lock2 is java.lang.Object@4e25154f
```

I took thread dump , and below is the code snippet of interest from thread dump.

```
"Thread-1" #11 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fb334859800 nid=0xa903 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700009359000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at com.example.threads.deadlock.Thread2.run(Thread2.java:26)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000007955f6480> (a java.lang.Object)
        - locked <0x00000007955f6490> (a java.lang.Object)

"Thread-0" #10 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fb334859000 nid=0x5503 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700009256000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at com.example.threads.deadlock.Thread1.run(Thread1.java:26)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000007955f6490> (a java.lang.Object)
        - locked <0x00000007955f6480> (a java.lang.Object)


Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"Thread-1":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fb33681fd58 (object 0x00000007955f6480, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "Thread-0"
"Thread-0":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fb33681fbf8 (object 0x00000007955f6490, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "Thread-1"

Java stack information for the threads listed above:
===================================================
"Thread-1":
        at com.example.threads.deadlock.Thread2.run(Thread2.java:26)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000007955f6480> (a java.lang.Object)
        - locked <0x00000007955f6490> (a java.lang.Object)
"Thread-0":
        at com.example.threads.deadlock.Thread1.run(Thread1.java:26)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000007955f6490> (a java.lang.Object)
        - locked <0x00000007955f6480> (a java.lang.Object)

Found 1 deadlock.
```

As can be seen the above thread dumps, there are lot of hex numbers like:

waiting to lock monitor **0x00007fb33681fd58** . 
object **0x00000007955f6480** .

How to I decipher these? We have "object", "lock monitor"  among others.

In general, as thread dumps are indispensable way of troubleshooting, but I struggle to see something (online or book) which can help make these things easy to understand.

Any help to get these things clear would be appreciated.

Comment: I would simply treat them as some unique number that identify the object or monitor  in the same report.

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal values are virtual memory addresses of the objects.

In Your case:

```
waiting to lock <0x00000007955f6480> this value is virtual memory address of 
the object that Thread-1 is trying to lock.

tid=0x00007fb334859800 this value is virtual memory address of native thread 
object of Thread-1.

waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fb33681fd58 this is the memory address of monitor associated 
with the object that Thread-1 is trying to lock. 
(which is object with address of 0x00000007955f6480)
```

More on monitor; each object in Java is associated with a monitor, which a thread can lock or unlock. You can think this as a memory location, where information about owner thread is stored.

Usefull links:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-read-a-thread-dump